# Just numbers in string

Tags: java, string, double

I have strings of randomly generated characters (eg. `138fj*28+/dg`).

How can I test if a given string consists of numbers alone. For example,

```
if(str="247339")
    true; 
else if(str="a245")
    false;
```

Comment: Have a look at regex pattern and matchers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two option, one is using regex other is parsing string.

Here is regex approach :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]*$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("138fj*28+/dg");

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(true);
            // number
        }else {
            System.out.println(false);
            // not
        }
    }
}
```

output is : false

Here is parse approch :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        try {
            double number = Double.parseDouble("138fj*28+/dg");
            System.out.println(true);
            // number
        }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println(false);
            // not
        }

    }
}
```

output is : false

Answer (score 1):

try to use matches method of Pattern class

```
boolean b = Pattern.matches("\\d+", "138fj*28+/dg");
 if(b)
   //number
 else
   // not a number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use matches method in String.
e.g.

```
System.out.println("Only integer   23343453 :"+("23343453".matches("\\d+")));
System.out.println("With character 2334a3453 :"+("2334a3453".matches("\\d+")));
System.out.println("With symbols   2*33434/53 :"+("2*33434/53".matches("\\d+")));

or

System.out.println("Only integer   23343453 :"+("23343453".matches("[0-9]+")));
System.out.println("With character 2334a3453 :"+("2334a3453".matches("[0-9]+")));
System.out.println("With symbols   2*33434/53 :"+("2*33434/53".matches("[0-9]+")));
```

output :

```
Only integer   23343453 :true
With character 2334a3453 :false
With symbols   2*33434/53 :false
Only integer   23343453 :true
With character 2334a3453 :false
With symbols   2*33434/53 :false
```